# How to have gradient type effect

Tags: modeling, materials

Im made a Hud background. And i want to make the center part blur (transparent) and from center it should go unblur like a gradient effect. Is it possible with the camera or other way .Any suggestion or help.Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: You could use the camera's depth of field but it would mean that you push the center of your object further

Answer (score 3):

You can setup your material like that :
[image]

The texture coordinate node control the position of the effect. I centered it on Circle.005 but you can create a new Empty if you want to fine tune the position.

The mapping node control the size (area of influence) of the effect.

The color ramp control the transition between fully transparent (black on the ramp) and fully emissive (white on the ramp).